# PHP: Mixed array from JSON to index based array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that is created using json_decode from an incoming JSON feed.  The feed has common elements in groups.  The elements that have multiples become indexed arrays, while the elements with single values come through as a named array.

It currently looks like this... (this is just a test example, as the file contains a lot more data)

```
Array
(
    [Items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [unit] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Fred
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [unit] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Wilma
                                    [1] => Barney
                                )
                        )
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [unit] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Betty
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Dino
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

It makes it hard to loop through the array because of the different variations of loops I would need.  Just to get the "name" value from the array I have to use multiple loop variations...

```
["Items"][0]["unit"]["name"] => Fred
["Items"][1]["unit"]["name"][0] => Wilma
["Items"][1]["unit"]["name"][1] => Barney
["Items"][2]["unit"][0]["name"] => Betty
["Items"][2]["unit"][1]["name"] => Dino
```

Where I would like to be able to use a single format. I need to be able to parse the array so it converts it into a totally indexed array.

And I would like it to look like this...

```
Array
(
    [Items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [unit] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Fred
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [unit] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Wilma
                                            [1] => Barney
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [unit] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Betty
                                        )
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Dino
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

So accessing everything would use a consistent formatted loop

```
["Items"][0]["unit"][0]["name"][0] => Fred
["Items"][1]["unit"][0]["name"][0] => Wilma
["Items"][1]["unit"][0]["name"][1] => Barney
["Items"][2]["unit"][0]["name"][0] => Betty
["Items"][2]["unit"][1]["name"][0] => Dino
```

Does anyone have any ideas, or know a simple function that would re-index the entire array into this format?

Comment: Can you show the json data that you are using for json_decode?

Comment: This is the JSON for this example.

{"Items":[{"unit":{"name":"Fred"}},{"unit":{"name":["Wilma","Barney"]}},{"unit":[{"name":"Betty"},{"name":"Dino"}]}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in a place I didn't even think to look, and that was in the JSON structure itself.

I found (by total accident) that json_decode() looks for square brackets "[]" and forces items inside to be indexed (so even if there is only one item it will give it a [0] index).

```
{"name":"Wilma"} 
Result
array["name"] = Wilma

{"name":["Wilma"]} 
Result
array["name"][0] = Wilma
```

So with a bit of playing around I turned the entire JSON import into a named/index array.  With a few replaces, and a substr (to remove the external braces, because the base is already an array), the following 6 lines have worked on every JSON file I have thrown at it.

So on the raw JSON, whether received as JSON or on the JSON from an array using json_encode(), apply the following...

```
$jsonStr = str_ireplace("{","[{",$jsonStr);
$jsonStr = str_ireplace("}","}]",$jsonStr);
$jsonStr = str_ireplace(":\"",":[\"",$jsonStr);
$jsonStr = str_ireplace("\"}","\"]}",$jsonStr);
$jsonStr = str_ireplace("\",\"","\"],\"",$jsonStr);
$jsonStr = substr($jsonStr, 1, -1);
```

Then push it through json_decode() and my PHP array looks exactly the way I want it to.

Thanks everyone for all of your input.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way around it. Here's one way:

```
<?php

$a = array();
$a["Items"][0]["unit"]["name"] = 'Fred';
$a["Items"][1]["unit"]["name"][0] = 'Wilma';
$a["Items"][1]["unit"]["name"][1] = 'Barney';
$a["Items"][2]["unit"][0]["name"] = 'Betty';
$a["Items"][2]["unit"][1]["name"] = 'Dino';

$b = array();

foreach ($a['Items'] as $k1 => $unit) {
    if (count($unit['unit']) == 1) {
        $unit['unit'] = array($unit['unit']);
    }   

    foreach ($unit['unit'] as $k2 => $name) {
        if (!is_array($name['name'])) {
            $name['name'] = array($name['name']);
        }   

        $b['Items'][$k1]['unit'][$k2]['name'] = $name;
    }   
}

print_r($b);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great start.  It does work for this example, but unfortunately there are about 20 different documents, and they don't always have the Items > unit > name structure. Although each individual document does have standards for each one, so I might just need to create a function for each document.

Answer (score 0):

Here `$array` is your input array that you have got after json_encode.

```
$unitArray = array_map(function($entry) {
    return $entry['unit'];
}, $array['Items']);

foreach($unitArray as $key => $unit) {
    if(is_array($unit)) {
        if(array_key_exists('name', $unit)) {
            $nameArray = array_map('getNamesKeyValues', $unit);
            $unitArray[$key] = $nameArray;
        } else {
            $temp = array('name' => array());
            foreach($unit as $k => $value) {
                if(is_array($value) && array_key_exists('name', $value) && count($value) == 1) {
                    $temp['name'][] = $value['name'];   
                }   
            }
            $unitArray[$key] = $temp;
        }
    } 
}
$array['Items'] = $unitArray;
var_dump($array);

function getNamesKeyValues($entry)
{
    if (is_array($entry)) {
        return $entry;
    } elseif(is_string($entry)) {
        return (array)$entry;
    } else {
        return (array)$entry;
    }
    return $entry;
}
```

This can be the solution for the below json:
`{"Items":[{"unit":{"name":"Fred"}},{"unit":{"name":["Wilma","Barney"]}},{"unit":‌​[{"name":"Betty"},{"name":"Dino"}]}]}`

If there are more different type of json then you have to write such kind of parsing logic for every json. 
Hope this will help you.

Comment: I've looked through the documents, and there's probably about 5 or 6 different labels that need to have keys [0], AND the array can be up to 15 levels deep.  So is there any way to write a recursive function that would find those keywords and perform the same as you have done above?

Comment: I think by recursive function it is not possible because we don't have stopping condition here.One more thing is that we have to check the string key e.g. "name" here again in numeric indexed nested array.